# Checking spacebar inside edit text for activating text to speech

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, text-to-speech, togglebutton

I'm still in high school and I don't understand kotlin that much and i need help. I have a toggle button that activates a code for a text to speech engine. On toggling the button, if you enter a space (" ") in edit text, it will activate the text to speech engine. But my code doesn't work after several tries.

```
val s_type: ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.st)
    s_type.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            // TOGGLE ENABLED
            input_tts.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            val text = input_tts.text.toString().trim()
            if(input_tts.text.toString().contains(" "))
                    input_tts.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    if (input_tts.text != null) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            tts_engine.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "tts1")
                        }
                    }
                    false
                })
        }
        else
        {
            //TOGGLE DISABLED
        }
    }
```

It would be nice if you could help me and also explain a bit of what your code means, since I'm not that good at Kotlin. Thanks

Comment: Honestly this would be a great time to learn debugging (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) - set a breakpoint on the ``val text = ...`` line, check what it gets set to and if that looks right, step through the code and look at where it goes... you can narrow down the problem and work out where it's going wrong. Once you get the hang of it it's incredibly useful! And it's not hard to do

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s == ' '){//your text here}
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            attempt[0] = s.toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I had a hard time translating it to Kotlin since what you wrote was Java